# Understanding Entity Framework optimistic concurrency (database wins) pattern

Tags: entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency

See [Resolving optimistic concurrency exceptions with Reload (database wins)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592904) :

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);
    blog.Name = "The New ADO.NET Blog";
    bool saveFailed;
    do
    {
        saveFailed = false;

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            saveFailed = true;

            // Update the values of the entity that failed to save from the store
            ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
        }

    } while (saveFailed);
}
```

Why the method `SaveChanges()` is called after `Reload()`? 
This call will never change the data in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree it's not too clear. The intention of this piece of code is in the sentence

> The entity is then typically given back to the user in some form and they must try to make their changes again and re-save.

So it would have been better if they had added a comment:

```
...
// User evaluates current values and may make new changes.
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
...
```